# How to convert object to XML document

Tags: java, xml, jsp, soap, webservice-client

I have imported WSDL files and I'm trying to create a web service client.

In this case I could able to send soap request (XML) and also can get the result as a object(Using sout),

> com.ech.cdem.client.AppointmentUpdateResponseAppointmentUpdateResult@45d6cba4

I could understand com.ech.cdem.client.AppointmentUpdateResponseAppointmentUpdateResult is a package.class name.

So result should be **@45d6cba4** as a object.
when I debug this object(whole result) and evaluate the result.then I could able to get expected result XML response.

```
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns=""><record><STATUS>Success</STATUS><MESSAGE>Appointment Number : 000262</MESSAGE></record></data-set>
```

how to print like that object as a xml document or something like...

further,

```
AppointmentUpdateResponseAppointmentUpdateResult result = service.appointmentUpdate(xmlInput);
System.out.println(result);
```

xmlInput is a String(request XML document) and AppointmentUpdateResponseAppointmentUpdateResult is a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my IDE (Intellij IDEA), I have an option called "Evaluate Expression". What it does is when debug some value (eg: "result" object), by changing that expression(debug value) we can evaluate (get) the result without running the program.

That's how I got my result.
In my case XML file came as an array.

Since how I got my output,

```
result.get_any()[0].getElementsByTagName("record").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).toString()
```

Without "Evaluate Expression" that kind of expression was imposible. So my advice is use your IDE's "Evaluate Expression" option.